# Why do I only see my master branch on github?

Tags: git, github, branch

For some reason my Branches are not showing up in Github. However, when I execute `git tag --all` they show up there which indicates they are not missing.

Why would I only see the Master Branch in Github when I clearly have multiple branches in the local repository?

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Don't post the question *before* you have tried anything, ask for help *after* you have tried a few things.

Comment: It's in the title. I'll repeat it in the content body. Note: I have an idea on the fix but that still doesn't mean it's the correct fix nor does it mean that it's not a valid question.

Comment: You have to push local branches individually. Git makes it really easy to create branch after branch but it doesn't automatically throw them up on the remote repo.

Comment: BenjiWiebe: Would it not be helpful for others who may run into the same issue to have this question posted here? Also, I may not known to try my own recommendation of a fix. Would I simply be advised to not ask a question in that case? Thanks.

Comment: I edited the Question to include my specific question. Any explanation for the down votes? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pushing only pushes the current branch. You need to push the branches that you want published, if that's all of them, then the answer your referenced : git push --all should help!

Answer (score 3):

So assuming you see a list of branches when you run:

```
git branch
```

all you have to do is run:

```
git push <remote-name> <branch-name>
```

Answer (score 2):

only the current master branch gets really pushed by `git push` if you want to push a seperate branch to the repo you *must* do `git push origin <branchname>` so give this a try...

this is also explained in the link you posted in your question..